# How to insert NULL value to a variable of image datatype?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net, logic

I want to insert null value to the variable of image datatype and then update the column of image datatype in the Database

```
Dim PHOTO as Image = row("PHOTO")
```

Here, row("PHOTO") is fetched from a DataTable. If row("PHOTO") is Null, I want to insert the null value in PHOTO variable.
I tried a lot but didn't succeed. Your help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you try: 
     If IsNothing(row("PHOTO"))

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. The error popups "Unable to insert null value in System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image"

Comment: Not so sure about vb.net, but shouldn't row("PHOTO") be equal to `DBNull.Value` and not to `Nothing`?

Comment: OK, please try to use: IsDbNull()

Comment: Used that one too. As its datatype is Image, so it is not accepting any other parameter/ value

Comment: Just Allow null in Database Schema and thats all. After that if you dont provide any value it will autometically treat as a null value.

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with a database. You need to do a bit of research on how to serialise Image .NET objects.

Comment: @BillingSystems,i resolved this type of issue in c#, if you want me to share c#code then i can. may be that code will help you to get out of it.....

Comment: @Waqas i have already checked it, Its fine overthere. Please share the code I wish that would be helpful for me.

Comment: @Alex please suggest me any because i have done enough RnD on that

Comment: @Billing Systems, well if you have done enough research and development then you have the code where you are saving an image to the database. Please post it.

Comment: Here is some part of the code


In code
For Each row As DataRow In DT_New_Users.Rows
 Dim PHOTO as Image = row("PHOTO")
 objNewDB.AddParameter("@PHOTO",PHOTO)
 'Execute Stored Procedure
next

In Stored Procedure
Declare @PHOTO AS IMAGE 

Insert into UserInfo(Photo)
Values(@PHOTO)

Comment: use simple this code  -->>       If Not IsDBNull(row("PHOTO")) And Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row("PHOTO")) Then
            Return PHOTO = row("PHOTO")
        Else
            Return ""
        End If

Comment: @Nazir Ullah Problem is the variable PHOTO of image datatype. It is not allowing to insert NULLS.

Comment: Please try the following (I've tried in my machine :-) ), use byte Array to convert the array into the Image object:

If dr("Photo").ToString() <> "" Then
    Dim image As [Byte]() = DirectCast(dr("PHOTO"), [Byte]())
..........
Then in the Else section:

Dim PHOTO as Image = Nothing

Comment: @lionheart Still not working

Comment: As @Alex asked, could you elaborate with some code that might tell us how the PHOTO data is saved in the DB?...
This issue seems to be with context to how the data is saved in DB rather than code itself. I'll try to reproduce it in my machine...

Comment: This is how data is saved in DB against the PHOTO:  0x424D36900100000000003600000028000000A0000000A000000001002000000000000090010000000000000000000000000. The string continues. I can't place the whole string here. 
I just need to insert the null value in the image data type column. I have checked and allowed null value to be saved in that column, still it is not accepting my NULL value.

Answer (score 3):

try following example,

```
If NOT IsDbNull(row("PHOTO")) Then
   //Do something
ELSE
   //your logic goes here
Dim PHOTO as Image=DBNull.Value;
End If
```

**EDIT**
As you mentioned in comment, In C# my approach that works for me is...

```
 byte[] bimage = null;
if (txtPic.Text != "")
                {
                    string image = txtPic.Text;
                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    bimage = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(bimage, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                    fs.Close();
                }
```

and now for stored procedure my image parameter will be as

```
if (bimage != null)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgdata", SqlDbType.Image).Value = bimage;
                else
                {
                    SqlParameter imageParameter = new SqlParameter("@imgdata", SqlDbType.Image);
                    imageParameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(imageParameter);
                }
```

Comment: On declaring the variable, the error popups:
Value of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image''

Comment: This is because System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image can be used only with NULL value (and not with System.DBNull) when talking about nullable object.